# How to loop through jquery objects in an array and display the desired result?

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I m newbie in jquery space and hope to learn much through Stackoverflow.

I have a Sharepoint 2010 list data item which has Choice data type allowing a user to checkbox more than one value. I m using SPService to get the list items. Below is the code:

```
    $().SPServices({
                  webURL: 'http://abc.def.com/Products',
                  operation: 'GetListItems',
                  listName: listName,
                  async: false,
                  CAMLQuery: query,
                  CAMLViewFields: fields,
                  CAMLRowLimit: 11,

                  completefunc:
                  function (xData, Status) 
    {        $(xData.responseXML).find("[nodeName=z:row]").each(function () 

    {
           $("#ProdList").val("-1");//Pre-filled with selected val.
           var myProd= $(this).attr("ows_Prod"); //displays in this format ;#myProd1;#myProd2;#

          //Here 1. i want to store myProd as an array.
                 2. eliminate ;#
                 3. store final array elements as myProd1, myProd2
                 4. Display myProd1
                            myProd2
                                    in the dropdown list.
           //


           $("#ProdList").append('<option>' + myProd+ '</option>');
      });   
    }

     });      

     });

    <body>
    <select class="Dropdowns" id="ProdList">
    <option value="-1">My ProdLists</option>
    </select>
    </body>
  Any pointers? Thanks.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit hard to figure out what the specifics are of your question.  I'm guessing that the comments in your code are describing the question.  Next time, I'd suggest you be a lot more specific with the details of your question in your text, not in the code.  But, given that, here's my guess at what you're trying to do.

You have a string that looks like this:

```
";#myProd1;#myProd2;#"
```

And, you'd like to get `myProd1` and `myProd2` into an array and then from that array added to a drop-down list.

```
// get product list
var myProd = $(this).attr("ows_Prod");
// clean up the ends
myProd = myProd.replace(/^;#|;#$/g, "");
// split into pieces
var myProdArray = myProd.split(";#");
// add each piece as an option to the drop-down
for (var i = 0; i < myProdArray.length; i++) {
    $("#ProdList").append('<option>' + myProdArray[i] + '</option>')
}
```

You can sort the array in dictionary order with:

```
myProdArray.sort();
```

You can remove dups from a sorted array with this:

```
var noDupArray = [];
noDupArray.push(myProdArray[0]);
for (var i = 1; i < myProdArray.length; i++) {
    if (myProdArray[i] != myProdArray[i-1]) {
        noDupArray.push(myProdArray[i]);
    }
}
```

So, if you wanted to both sort and remove dups, you could use this code:

```
var myProd = $(this).attr("ows_Prod");
myProd = myProd.replace(/^;#|;#$/g, "");
var myProdArray = myProd.split(";#");
// sort
myProdArray.sort();
// remove dups
var noDupArray = [];
noDupArray.push(myProdArray[0]);
for (var i = 1; i < myProdArray.length; i++) {
    if (myProdArray[i] != myProdArray[i-1]) {
        noDupArray.push(myProdArray[i]);
    }
}
// add each piece as an option to the drop-down
for (i = 0; i < noDupArray.length; i++) {
    $("#ProdList").append('<option>' + noDupArray[i] + '</option>')
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch jfriend00. It worked. I will definitely try to be more specific in describing a question next time. Thanks again for your help. :)

Comment: How do I make sure that I don't have duplicates in my dropdown list for the above code? I also want my myProdArray to be sorted (ASC). Any pointers? Thanks.

Comment: Sorting and dedupping added to my answer.

Comment: I have two list items and they have same values for myProd.For eg. let's say SharePoint2010
I have to make sure I only put SharePoint 2010 once in the dropdown list.
With the code above, I could not eliminate the duplicacy. Any guidance please? Thanks a lot for prompt response.

Comment: It seems to work fine here in this sample http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/yCauH/ if implemented as above.  There are multiple dups in the attribute, but no dups are put in the drop-down.  If you want further help, you'll have to show your actual implementation.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sspb485/tsuc7/    The code may not run because all jQuery files are not present but i have tried my best to explain. I have provided o/p comments to each line.

Comment: What exactly do you get for the value of `var Serv_skill = $(this).attr("ows_Services");`?  The code in your jsfiddle isn't runnable so I can't see for myself.  If it follows the format you described earlier, dups will be removed.  If not, they won't.

Comment: my SharePoint list has a field Services(which is a checkbox). The list contains two items. Fora first list item as well as for the second list item, the values for Services field are both SharePoint. So for each list item, json obejct is

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what your last comment means.  I simply do not understand.  I asked a question in my previous comment that you did not answer.

Comment: my SharePoint list has a field Services(which is a checkbox). The list contains two items. Fora first list item as well as for the second list item, the values for Services field are both SharePoint. So for each list item, json obejct is var Serv_skill = $(this).attr("ows_Services");//Returns ;#SharePoint;#

Comment: sorry for the confusions. Comment bpx didn't allow me to edit my comments. That's y it was incomplete. I hope I answered your Q. Thanks for promptly answering. Really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: OK, I didn't understand that the code I was suggesting was inside a `.each()` loop and getting called multiple times.  I've suggested a different version here that moves the dedup code outside the loop: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/SvAMk/.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sspb485/SvAMk/3/ . That is correct. Now the problem is sometimes my data results come in this format arr_Serv_skill.push($(this).attr("ows_Services").replace(/^;#|;#$/g, ""));// it might be something like this ["Mobile and Tablet", "SharePoint", "SharePoint;#Portals", "SharePoint;#Portals;#Andriod"] and so forth. Right now the drop down list shows Mobile and Tablet  SharePoint  SharePoint;#Portals  SharePoint;#Portals;#Andriod. Sorting is good but i need only one instance of SharePoint , only one instance of Portals and likewise. Any idea? TIA

Comment: Change this line: `arr_Serv_skill.push($(this).attr("ows_Services").replace(/^;#|;#$/g, ""));` to this: `arr_Serv_skill = arr_Serv_skill.concat($(this).attr("ows_Services").replace(/^;#|;#$/g, "").split(";#"));
` as seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/SvAMk/4/.

Comment: Since you're pretty new to SO, do you realize that you should select an answer as your preferred answer by clicking the checkmark to the  left of the answer and, if it was helpful to you, by also upvoting?

Comment: Yes I do want to select your most recent answer as my preferred answer but I didn't see the Checkmark to the left of the answer. I also want to vote for it. How? Thanks.

Comment: I did see the Checkmark and clicked on it. Now its Green meaning to me, that was accepted as my preferred answer.